# Problem with finding shock location via the separable ODE $\dot s=(s+1)/2t$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics

I want to solve the following separable ODE to find an expression for the shock location $x=s(t)$. The initial condition I prescribe to this problem will be that $s(2)=3$.

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{s+1}{2t}$$

Here is my working for the problem:

As this is a separable ODE, we consider,

$$\int\frac{1}{s+1}ds=\int\frac{1}{2t}dt$$

$$\iff\ln(s+1)=\ln(2t)+c$$

$$\iff s+1=2t+d$$

Where we take $d:=\exp(c)$. Then, applying our initial condition, we get that $d=0$. So that our expression for the location of the shock is given by,

$$s(t)=2t-1$$

However, I should be getting $s(t)=2\sqrt {2t}-1$. What have I done wrong in the above? This should be incredibly easy and I know I'm missing something terribly simple.

Comment: $\int\frac{dt}{2t}=\frac{1}{2}\ln t$ and not $\ln(2t)$...

Comment: ...and thus $s+1=c\sqrt{t}$ ...

Comment: As I thought it was something silly. I was mixing up my rules of logs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{d(s+1)}{dt}=\frac{s+1}{2t}, \quad \frac{2 d(s+1)}{s+1}=\frac{dt}{t}  $$

Integrating

$$ \frac{(s+1)^2}{t}= c_1$$

simplify getting

$$ s = \sqrt{tc_1} -1 = c_2\sqrt{t} -1 $$

$c_2$ evaluates with $s(2)=3, \rightarrow 2 \sqrt 2 $

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I see what your hint is telling me. Why do you consider $d/dt$ of $s+1$?

Comment: Derivative of $1$ is $0$. The introduction of $s+1$ is a convenient rope-in to recognize logs by subsequent integrations.